# CS50 mario pyramid upside down can't figure why

Tags: c, cs50

I thought long and hard before asking this in here but I've spent too much time now trying to figure this one out without cheating.
The CS50 mario ps1 (less comfortable) asks for a *simple left align (at first) pyramid, but my code is giving me it upside down and I can't figure why.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Pyramid Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i ; j++)
            printf("#");
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) 
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this type of questioning shows up regularly here but I really do need your help.
Thanks in advance.

edit:

- expected result:

```
........#
.......##
......###
.....####
....#####
...######
..#######
.########
```

- I can change the dots to spaces afterwards, this is just for visualisation;
- the restriction for height is 8, so I guess that each line has always eight characters;
- I actually added trailing spaces so that the pyramid could be right aligned, I've metioned wrong before;
- I'm going to check the [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/);
- Sorry, I'm new to this, I didn't know there was a difference between here and stack exchange, gonna look into that.

*Sorry for the "meh" english, it is not my native language.

Comment: Show the expected figure of the pyramid.

Comment: now is a good time to learn how to debug a small program.  step through it by hand if needed, write the variable values down, and examine what happens

Comment: See also [How to debug small programs?](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Do you need the trailing spaces?  If not,  remove the second nested `for` loop.  (You might need that loop later when you have to right-justify the pyramid, though it would probably appear before the hash (`#`) printing loop.)  How many hashes does the first loop output when `i` is `0`?  How many should it output?

Comment: You should consider asking this on the CS50 stack exchange https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

See what is the difference between my and your code (especially how to count):

```
void draw(int n, int align, int dir)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        if(align)
        {
            for(int s = 0; s < (dir ? (n - i) : i - 1); s++)
            {
            printf(" ");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < (dir ? i  : (n - i + 1)) ; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    draw(8,1,0);
    printf("\n");
    draw(8,1,1);
    printf("\n");
    draw(8,0,0);
    printf("\n");
    draw(8,0,1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7YT16j

Answer (score 0):

> my code is giving me it upside down and I can't figure why

Let's see what the code looks like

```
// There's a loop executed n times. The body prints a line, so n lines are printed.
// In case you have doubts, the characters are normally printed top to bottom and
// left to right.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    // The following loop prints (n - i) characters '#' at the beginning
    // of each line. That's NOT what you are supposed to do, kind the opposite.
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i ; j++)
        printf("#");
    // You should first print the spaces, then the '#'s, starting from 1 '#' at
    // the first line and increasing the number by one at each line (so you have
    // to change the condition in the loop accordingly).

    // This loop prints the right amount of spaces, but only after
    // all the '#'s and just before the end of the line, so that you just
    // can't see them (change the printed char to '.' to visualize those).
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) 
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    // Note that you could use putchar('\n'), here and previously, to print
    // only one char, instead of using printf() to print string literals. 
    printf("\n");
}
```